# QML State Machine crashing with signal

Tags: qt, qml

The following QML state machine crashes on launch when I run it:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQml.StateMachine 1.0

Item {
  id: thingy
  signal somethingHappened

  StateMachine {
    initialState: stateA
    running: true

    State {
      id:stateA
      onEntered:console.log('entered A')

      SignalTransition {
        targetState: stateB
        signal: thingy.onSomethingHappened
      }
    }

    State {
      id: stateB
      onEntered: console.log('entered B')
    }
  }
}
```

The output is simply "The program has unexpectedly finished."

If I change `signal: thingy.onSomethingHappened` to `signal: thingy.nope`—or if I remove the line `signal somethingHappened`—then it works as expected (except that I can't actually get a signal to trigger a state change).

Am I doing something wrong? Any idea why this is crashing?

<sup>Using Qt 5.6 on Ubuntu x64, if it matters.</sup>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PEBCAK. I should have written the name of the signal without the `on` prefix:

```
signal: thingy.somethingHappened
```

It <strike>is</strike> was a bug in the Qt runtime that it segfaults when the transition signal is incorrectly setup like this. This bug has been filed (and fixed) as http://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-53596